# How to increment the values in a dictionary without using a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, increment

For example I have the following set up:

```
dic = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0} 
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

If the element in the token exists in the dictionary keys, increment the value by 1.

How do I do this without using the loop?
I have the following `for` loop right now

```
for key in dict.keys(): 
    if key in tokens: 
         dict[key] += 1
```

Comment: You could use `collections.Counter()`

Comment: You can have a loop, but your current loop is inefficient. (You end up scanning the list for each key in the dict.) It would be better to loop over each of the tokens, check if the key exists in the dict, and then increment.

Comment: Does dictionary comprehension count as a loop? `dic = {k:tokens.count(k) for k in dic.keys()}`

Comment: I will take that if dictionary comprehension is faster than for loop. @JohnnyMopp

Comment: You didn't say you wanted faster - just no loop. In this case a loop may be faster since in my example, `count` is called for each key which means 3 passes through the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive approach with update the dictionary by slicing one by one each tokens.

```
dic = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0} 
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"] 

def key_counter(d, tokens):
    if tokens == []:
        return
    if tokens[0] in d:
        d[tokens[0]] += 1

    key_counter(d, tokens[1:])

key_counter(dic, tokens)

print(dic)
```

Output

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a *no-loop* version using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

dic = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0}
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

res = Counter(filter(dic.__contains__, tokens))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'C': 2, 'A': 1, 'B': 1}
```

**UPDATE**

If there is a key in `dic`, that is not present in `tokens`, you could do:

```
from collections import Counter

dic = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "Z": 0}
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

dic.update(Counter(filter(dic.__contains__, tokens)))
print(dic)
```

**Output**

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'Z': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that initial values in dic are always zero, you can map the dictionary keys to the tokens's count method and reform the dictionary using zip:

```
dic = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0} 
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

dic = dict(zip(dic,map(tokens.count,dic)))
print(dic)
# {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

This way, you have no import library and no for-loop (not even inside a comprehension).

but if you are concerned about performance and don't mind using a library, I would suggest using the Counter class instead of the list's .count() method:

```
 dic = dict(zip(dic,map(Counter(tokens).__getitem__,dic)))
```

If initial values in dic can be other than zero, you will need to add them in:

```
dic = dict(zip(dic,map(lambda k:dic[k]+tokens.count(k),dic)))
# or 
dic = dict(zip(dic,map((Counter(dic)+Counter(tokens)).__getitem__,dic)))
```

Alternatively, you can write a recursive function (but that is much slower and will be limited by the maximum recursion depth):

```
def countTokens(counts,token,*more):
    if token in counts: counts[token] += 1
    if more: countTokens(counts,*more)

dic = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0}
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

countTokens(dic,*tokens)
print(dic)
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate on `tokens` to read them all, not only on the keys you already set

```
dic = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0}
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

for token in tokens:
    if token in dic:
        dic[token] += 1

print(dic)  # {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 3}
```

---

Without a for loop you could use `collections.Counter`, but that doesn't filtering

```
dic = Counter(tokens)
print(dic)  # {'C': 3, 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1, 'F': 1}
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't want a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use comprehension

```
dic = { k:v+tokens.count(k) for k,v in dic.items() }
```

but this is inefficient if the dictionary has a large number of items and tokens is a small list

Comment: What's implicit about a `for` loop?

Comment: You are correct. It is a for loop so not implicit.

Answer (score 0):

= {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0}
tokens = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
1# convert list to set tokens
2# convert set to list
3# sort list
4# delete character D , E , F
5# convert list to tuples
6# convert to tuple to dictionary and apply dictionary
7# simple trick you take form user input

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).